# Subsetting dataframe via a list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, subset

I dummified one column in my data frame using get_dummies but that produced an additional 400 columns. The issue is that I would like to subset the data frame which now has over 700 columns to run below operation

```
replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna()
```

I tried isolating the new columns generated by get_dummies by storing them in a list which I initializaed as col1. 
When I tried to subset the df using

```
df = df[['var1','var2','var3',[col1] ]]
```

I got an error msg saying " ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence''

Is there a way to go about subsetting the new dummies without having to type them all out when subsetting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an asterisk to unpack your list in the column selection

Otherwise you're passing in your list as a sublist into the column list. Your current method becomes:

```
df[['var1','var2','var3',['sub1','sub2','sub3']]]
```

But :

```
df = df[['var1','var2','var3',*col1]]
```

is unpacked to

```
df[['var1','var2','var3','sub1','sub2','sub3']]
```